# Raise a validation error if the has_many children are not valid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many

I have a problem with a `has_many` association that shouldn't validate until all children are valide.

### Setup

```
rails g scaffold Hotel name
rails g scaffold RoomCategory name hotel:references
```

**app/models/hotel.rb**

```
class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :room_categories, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :room_categories,
                                :reject_if => 
                                proc {|attributes| attributes['name'].blank?},
                                allow_destroy: true
end
```

**app/models/room_category.rb**

```
class RoomCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :hotel

  validates :name,
            presence: true,
            uniqueness: { scope: :hotel }
end
```

The idea is that a given `hotel` can not have two `room_categories` with the same name.

### Question

How can I ensure that the following `hotel` example does not validates true?

```
>> hotel = Hotel.new(name: 'Example')
>> hotel.room_categories.build(name: 'Suite')
>> hotel.room_categories.build(name: 'Suite')
>> hotel.save
>> hotel.valid?
=> true
```

Thank you!

Comment: Same problem. No difference between using :hotel_id and :hotel

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :room_categories, :reject_if => lambda { |a|  a[:name].blank?  }, :allow_destroy => true
```

Comment: That's not a solution for the given problem. I want to have a valid child. I do not want to write a second validation in the reject_if part.

Answer (score 0):

The validation of associated options controlled by "validate" option.
So you may:

has_many :room_categories, dependent: :destroy, validate: false